# ElasticSearch - Julia

Tags: elasticsearch, connection, julia

I am trying to use elasticsearch with Julia ,when I try to connect to my index in Kibana I get this error :

> PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#= /home/J1028071/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/pyfncall.jl:43 =# @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr, kw))))) <class 'elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError'> SerializationError('Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html')

Here is my code :

```
using PyCall
es = pyimport(“elasticsearch”)
js = pyimport(“json”)
client = es.Elasticsearch(“http://kibana-cig:5601”)
elastic_info = es.Elasticsearch.info(client)
```

If anyone has ever had this error or knows how to fix it…

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code could be about passing the client object back from Julia to Python.

BTW you do not need Python's JSON. PyCall will translate Python dictionaries to Julia's `Dict`s.

This used to work for me

```
using PyCall
es= pyimport("elasticsearch")
client = es.Elasticsearch() #provide con info if needed
```

And now I just call methods of the `client` object rather than passing it around:

```
client.info()  

dat = Dict("col1"=>"some text", "col2"=>"more text")
res = client.index(index="data", doc_type="data", id="1", body=dat)

q = Dict("query"=>Dict("match"=>Dict("col1"=>Dict("query"=>"some text"))))

client.search("data",body=q)["hits"]["hits"]
```

Another thing. Most likely you are connecting to Kibana GUI rather than Elasticsearch API. Instead try using:

```
client = es.Elasticsearch("http://yourelastichostname:5601")
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native Julia implementation - [ElasticsearchClient.jl](https://github.com/OpenSesame/ElasticsearchClient.jl)

```
using ElasticsearchClient

client = ElasticsearchClient.Client()

body = (
  query=(
    match=(
      field="find something",
    ),
  ),
)

# Methods are exported from API module
response = ElasticsearchClient.search(client, body=body)

@show response.body["took"]
```

That is significantly faster than `pyimport("elasticsearch")` implementation especially in multi-thread case.